# Pandas value_counts() returns non unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of surgical activity data that has 58 columns and 200,000 records. One of the columns is treatment specialty. Each row corresponds to a patient encounter. I want to see the relative conribution of medical specialties.One column is 'treatment_specialty'. I have used

`df['treatment_specialty'].value_counts(normalize=true)`

to get the relative proprtions of each specialty. This below is returned (no 
errors). The specialties have codes eg 150 is neurosurgery.

`df.head()`

```
150    0.642710
150    0.186934
218    0.062673
108    0.048300
218    0.018964
```

There are 69 records and a lot of the specialties have duplicate entries. Could I have some whitespace in the dataframe or is there another reason why the specialty codes are not unique?

Comment: It might be a matter of whitespace, have you tried using `.nunique()` to check the number of unique values? Can you share at least some data? See: [mcve]

Comment: Unfortunately the data has identifiable fields so its difficult. `.nunique()` gives me the same 69 values as the table above suggesting there is something different about the two '150' and '218' values eg above. I will have a look for whitespace.

Comment: Print the values to a list, you’ll clearly see any whitespace issues

Comment: @capnahab Try running `.str.strip().value_counts()` on the column, then you’ll know for sure.

Comment: Can't have had much there because using `.str.strip()` on the series has had no effect. I wonder if the Dtype (object) is at fault . Will change to int.

Comment: _I wonder if the Dtype (object) is at fault ._ The dtype itself shouldn't be the issue, what matters is whether all the values have the same type (str). It's easy to check, though, you can just look at the result of `df['treatment_specialty'].map(type)`.

Comment: There are 400 or so '&' values in there, - not sure why. I will change them to int as the code is numeric.